# How can I get my iCloud ID password reset?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, password

So last week I bought a new iphone15, and the sales clerk at the phone store encouraged me to make a quick “throw away” iCloud ID for in store setup, since as he said, “I could just change it later.”

The phone took over an hour, before finally just failing to set up. When I tried to reset it, my iCloud password no longer worked, and I have good reason to believe it has been hacked.

The problem is that without the iCloud ID password(which no longer works), I can’t finish setting up the phone, access the App Store, or reset the phone to fix the issue. I can’t return it unless the iCloud is unlocked, and apple support isn’t responding to my multiple requests to reset the password via the iforgot web page.

Any direction would be a blessing, as my brand new iPhone is currently little better than an over priced flip phone.

Comment: I'd be straight back to the store for my money back, or a real Apple Store with my receipt. Depends on what territory you live in, but often you're at better advantage buying online these days. tbh, I only buy directly from Apple these days.

Comment: To reset an AppleID password, start at https://iforgot.apple.com/.

Comment: I tried to go back to the store, but they wouldn’t return it(even with receipt). I also called apple support but was not able to be helped. They said just to use the iforgot.apple.com, but that hasn’t helped and it’s been a week now. Feeling frustrated.